Why does moving a postgres table from one tablespace to another take so long
Why does moving a postgres table from one tablespace to another take so long (and how can I speed it up)
I have a postgres database with two main tablespaces, one on a SDD, the other on magnetic HDD.
Occasionally I need to move some very large tables from the SDD to the HDD using ALTER TABLE... SET TABLESPACE... this works ok but can take several hours.
I know that I can find the physical location for the table being moved by SELECT pg_relation_filepath('myTableName'); which in this case returns the partial path pg_tblspc/59626/PG_13_202007201/59627/890785 If I switch from postgres to the operating system I can local several dozen files called 890785.nnn (where nnn is a number) I assume (please correct if I'm wrong) that these files make up the bulk of the table data?
I can monitor this directory, and see the files are being copied across as the ALTER TABLE command runs.
There are several GBytes of files here, experimentation shows me that I can copy the files (via windows) in about on tenth of the time it takes postgres to move them.
My question is, why does postgres take so long? is it doing something more than just a move? if so, why? And most importantly, is there anyway of speeding it up? (BTW - all other users are disconnected before running ALTER TABLESPACE...

You might look here - it covers Linux - but if you have symbolic links, as the post suggests, maybe you can stop your server, copy over the files and then change the symlink? No expert on Windows - you'll just have to try it? Let me know if it pans out!

PostgreSQL performs some validation and integrity checks during the move. This includes ensuring that indexes and references remain valid. The process might also involve rebuilding the indexes, which can be time-consuming for large tables.
To speed it up, you can:

Disable WAL Archiving, in case you're using it.

Increase Maintenance Work Memory.

You can move the table in smaller chunks instead of the entire table at once. You can partition the table and move partitions one at a time.


I hope this helps with your issue.

How would WAL archiving negatively affect ALTER TABLE? Why would copying something in smaller chunks be faster than copying the same volume of data at once?

@mustaccio The process of moving a table involves generating WAL entries, which are written to disk, increasing the overall I/O load on the system.
Also, moving data in smaller chunks has many advantages, such as better FS operations, parallelism, avoiding using swap memory, avoiding network congestions (if it is copied to a different server), being easier to handle, and probably more.

It sounds like you don't understand what WAL archiving is.
